# VBA Excel clear contents after parentheses of a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, parentheses

For a small procedure within a larger VBA Excel script I have the below code:

```
Worksheets(1).Columns("J:K").Select
For Each cell In Selection
   If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
   cell.Clear
   End If
Next
```

The code searches for all yellow cells within columns J and K and clears the contents.
However I would like to have the code clear just a part of the contents of these yellow cells. These cells contain a formula and I would like to clean everything after the last parentheses of these formula's, so the "-1" in this case.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D147;'https://.....VAS pivot'!$B$2:$E$728;2;0);0)-1
```

When cleared I would like to color these cells blue.
Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `InStrRev` to search for the paranthesis in the yellow cells formula *from the right side*. Then just cut it off at that position:

```
Worksheets(1).Columns("J:K").Select
For Each cell In Selection
   If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
      Dim pos As Integer
      pos = InStrRev(cell.Formula, ")")
      cell.Formula = Left(cell.Formula, pos)
   End If
Next
```